# Throw someone (to / in / into) [prison / jail / etc.]

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I was wondering which preposition is the correct one with the words like "prison", "jail", "detention center" or "slammer"?

Example:

1. They finally caught him and threw him......prison / jail. 
   a. to 
   b. in 
   c. into
2. He was arrested and was thrown..........detention center. 
   a. to 
   b. in 
   c. into

I am quite sure that "in" and "into" work with them all, but regarding "to" I still have my doubts. However, I think the best answer for both examples is "in".
Please correct me if I am mistaken.
Thank you.

Comment: Using 'to' would be wrong as you say. Items 2 and 3 need an article (2: indefinite, 3: definite) but not item 1. So bizzarre, hey?

Comment: That business about *breath some fresh air and know what's what* looks like an idiomatic usage inappropriately translated "word-for-word" from some other language. To ***know what's what*** (have the wisdom of experience) is perfectly natural in English, but ***breath[e] [some] fresh air*** means nothing to me in this context.

Comment: Although you throw someone INTO prison, you sentence / condemn / send / confine them TO prison.

Comment: You were right @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica. That was a word-to-word translation. I edited the thread. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Well @RonaldSole, hence we can throw someone **INTO** (prison / jail / detention center / slammer). **Not "IN" or "TO**". Do you confirm?

Comment: For the relevant "preposition idiomacy", just compare *thrown **in** prison* and *thrown **into** prison* in [Google NGrams.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thrown+in+prison%2Cthrown+into+prison&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthrown%20in%20prison%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthrown%20into%20prison%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthrown%20in%20prison%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthrown%20into%20prison%3B%2Cc0) Is there still a question?